# echo in reverse order from mysql_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

Ok here's the trick.
In the query I'm getting the right results from a table named messages. (Its fetching the last 10 messages ordered by the time inserted in reversed order) here's the query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT time, username, message
                      FROM messages ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
```

And than later those messages are printed inside div via ajax with

```
while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $item['time']." - ".$item['username']." - ".$item['message'];
}
```

But the printed result I want to print them only in the reversed order.
Tip: If I use ASC in the ORDER BY clause I don't get the last inserted messages.

Is this possible to do inside php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store your data & than use [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php),

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $items[] = $row;
}

$items = array_reverse($items ,true);

foreach($items as $item){
   echo $item['time']." - ".$item['username']." - ".$item['message'];
}
```

Comment: that was cool, I didn't knew about array_reverse. Marking as answer as soon as possible

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I would use a subquery personally. Im kinda anal about having my data come out of MySQL exactly how I want it, but the `array_reverse` method will work fine too. Here is my example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (
                      SELECT time, username, message
                      FROM messages ORDER BY time 
                      DESC LIMIT 10) result 
                      ORDER BY time ASC   
                    ");
```

Comment: I tried your solution too but I am getting an error "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..." EDIT: I got it it was syntax error I found muself. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

Use: [array_unshift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) - Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array

```
$items = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_unshift($items,$row);
}

foreach($items as $item){
   echo $item['time']." - ".$item['username']." - ".$item['message'];
}
```

Heres a useless but quick example. I hope it's still there: [Simple example](http://codepad.org/yiTYPvLl)