# Reverse results of array from mysql fetch

Tags: php, mysql

Versions: MySql 5.5, PHP 5.4

The following query returns the 5 most recent match dates for football teams, as well as their goal deficits, and match id.

```
$get_form = $conn->query("
SELECT (GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst) AS deficit, MatchID AS matchid 
FROM matches 
WHERE HomeTeamID = $homeid AND MatchDate < '$today'
ORDER BY MatchDate DESC
LIMIT 5
");
```

I am using the fetch shown below to retrieve the 5 results using PHP.

```
while($data = $get_form->fetch_assoc())
   {
   if($data['deficit'] < 0)
       echo"Win ";
   else
       echo"Loss ";
   }
```

But the results currently appear in descending chronological order, from left to right. I would much rather have them appearing in ascending chronological order, from right to left.

It has been recommended to me that I change ORDER BY to ASC, but this would instead just return the five oldest matches. I only want the five most recent (before today's date) to be returned in the result set.

Comment: `select from (select) order by`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456172/echo-in-reverse-order-from-mysql-fetch-assoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT (GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst) AS deficit, MatchID AS matchid 
    FROM matches 
    WHERE HomeTeamID = $homeid AND MatchDate < ?
    ORDER BY MatchDate DESC
    LIMIT 5
) X
ORDER BY MatchDate;
```